# iPhone: SBJsonParser source for iOS 5

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use SBJsonParser in my iOS 5 project. But, its not compiling in Xcode 4.2 and throws many errors for "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'". I have to now remove all autorelease/release/retain from from the complete set of SBJsonParser folder (or) set Xcode project setting ARC to "No". I can't do this both. Because, there are so many number of files, which i can't make removing all release/autorelease/retain used, and also I need to have ARC to "Yes" as my other files are dependent on it.

Could someone please share with me how can i get iOS 5 supported SBJsonParser files?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the 3.1 Alpha instead, it's ARC compatible. Even though it's an alpha release, I found it stable for my standard use.

Comment: Do you know that iOS5 has a great json api? Why do you need a third party framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/stig/json-framework

[image]